# Interchange of trace and infimum

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, supremum-and-infimum, trace

Let be such   $f( \cdot,t): \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where  $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
How to show that the following is true 
\begin{align}
\text{Trace } \left(\inf_t f(X,t) \right)  \le \inf_{t} \text{Trace } \left( f(X,t) \right)
\end{align}

we can assume that $f(X,t) \succeq 0$ (positive).

Comment: what is the definition of $inf_{t}f(X,t)$ ?

Comment: The minimal element of the ordering $\succeq$. Is that not a good definition? I am still learning a lot of things.

Comment: Do we assume $f$ is symetric here?

Comment: @Ben Yes, the output of $f$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: I am not sure whether $inf_t f(X,t)$ is well-defined since it seems that $preceq$ is just a partial ordering.

Comment: @Ben But since $f(X,t) \succeq 0$, doesn't that imply that there is a minimal element?

Comment: You can simplify the statement by writing $X_t$ instead of $f(X,t)$ everywhere. Further, yes, your set is bounded below, but I don't know if the set of self-adjoint matrices is order complete. But if you ignore that, basically all you have to show is $Tr(A)\leq Tr(B)$ if $A \preceq B$.

Comment: @PhoemueX thanks. I and the result you mention follows because trace preserves the order. I think I can take it from here.